# Xcode Not Immediately Recognizing New Classes (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, class, header-files

I've been working with Xcode for about 5 months now and I just recently ran across a problem when I add a new class. If I add a new class, say for example "CustomCell" and I try to import '#import CustomCell.h' into a different .m file it will give me an error saying 'CustomCell.h file not found' even though it's right there on the list. I've had no problem with this in the past and I know what I'm doing when it comes to importing (at least I haven't changed the way I previously went about it when it worked).

I've had this problem more than once recently and sometimes if I just close out XCode and restart it it will recognize the class. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a quick way to just refresh the project to see if Xcode can recognize the new class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Close all your projects, open the organizer (from the window menu), make sure the correct project is selected, then opposite 'derived data' click delete.

After that, close xcode, re-open it, open your project, clean it, and everything should work okay.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. (I have to wait four minutes before I can accept your answer apparently, I will ASAP).

Comment: Close Xcode > Open Xcode > Create a new file.  This worked for me. I did not have to clean anything.

Answer (score 18):

**Multiple Targets:** Make sure your file belongs to the necessary targets!

---

For a new file, make sure the appropriate targets are checked.

[image: xCode Screenshot]

---

For an existing file, check the file inspector to verify target membership.

[image: xCode Screenshot]

Comment: This is the correct answer. If your Swift file has multiple target memberships, any class dependencies requires those files to have the same target membership.

Comment: Interesting--I had a view controller in targets <AppName> and <AppNameTests> and I added a new view controller that was only in targets <AppName>. Adding the target <AppNameTests> to the new view controller based on this answer fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, in my case when creating new methods for my class, the other class called test did not see these methods because the target was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For those dealing with the same issue and the above solution failed to solve it, make sure you don't have the

> [circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767811/circular-import-issues-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

issue like i had. It happened with me as i had complex code and i failed to realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode not seeing any new class I created for a Watch OS2 app I am working on.

Eventually I figured out that it saw the new classes I created in the "extension" directory,  but that every class I created in the "app" directory of my project would not show.

What worked for me was creating a new .swift file in the extension, then moving both the reference in the project and the actual file manually to the proper location. After that, I was able to instantiate these classes in my view controller.

Hope that helps any other struggling watch app makers.