# When creating a property for an instance of a viewController, the viewController cannot be found

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a property for an instance of a viewController, like so,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailsViewController *videoViewController;
```

but I get an error saying that:

`DetailsViewController` is an unknown type name

The view controller is definitely imported like so,

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show the complete header file and show the contents of DetailsViewController.h

Comment: I think, you are facing circular import problem, seems [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767811/circular-import-issues-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Circular imports, always write Import statements in .m file, and use forward declaration in .h file.

In .h file

```
@class DetailsViewController;
```

In .m file

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"
```

## OR

For private properties, use Objective - C extensions, i.e,

Im .m file

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()<YourProtocolList>

@property(nonatomic, strong) DetailsViewController *detailViewController;

@end


@implementation MasterViewController
//Your implementation stuff
@end
```

In case of inheritance, you may need to import in .h file.