# I have declared my instance method in customized class .h file but still can not find the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

using xCode 6.1.1, Objective C

I am a beginner to Objective C and now is trying to extend some other methods to a existing APP project of iOS4.

After I implemented the new method and called it by my ViewController_2, it worked weird: the method is called but it did not receive the argument. But if I called the same method in the existing ViewController, it works fine.

Can someone tell me what's the problem with my class?

Here is my code:

// my customized class
AnimationObjectContainer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface AnimationObjectContainer : NSObject
...
- (void)flashImagesForSecs:(CGFloat)seconds;
...
@end
```

AnimationObjectContainer.m

```
#import "AnimationObjectContainer.h"
@implementation AnimationObjectContainer
- (void)flashImagesForSecs:(CGFloat)seconds
{
    NSLog(@"flashImagesForSecs: is called. seconds = %f", seconds);
}
@end
```

// existing project ViewController
ViewController.m

```
AnimationObjectContainer *container = [[AnimationObjectContainer alloc] init];
[container flashImagesForSecs:30];   // Succeed.
```

// my customized ViewController, inherited ViewController.h
ViewController_2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController_2 : ViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
...
@end
```

ViewController_2.m

```
#import "ViewController_2.h"
#import "AnimationObjectContainer.h"
@implementation ViewController_2
...
AnimationObjectContainer *container = [[AnimationObjectContainer alloc] init];
// Warning displayed here: Instance method '-flashImagesForSecs:' not found(return type defaults to 'id')
[container flashImagesForSecs:30];   // Succeed but output: 2015-02-09 10:28:28.959 Fomm Panel[2728:1765749] flashImagesForSecs: is called. seconds = 0.000000
...
@end
```

Comment: You need to `#import "AnimationObjectContainer.h"` in your ViewController_2.m file.  Each .m file is compiled separately and the compiler only sees what you `#import` in each .m file.

Comment: Thanks your comment! But I have already import "AnimationObjectContainer.h" in ViewController_2.m and the issue is still there. Updated the code.

Comment: In any case, the compiler for `ViewController_2.m` is not seeing your method declaration for `-flashImagesForSecs:` (or you have a typo in the method name).  A common problem is circular imports.  Trace back all of the .h files imported by ViewController_2.m and look for circular .h imports.  Use forward-class-declarations to minimize the `#imports` in your .h files.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767811/circular-import-issues-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch

Comment: #import _before_ the `@implementation` section, not inside it.

Comment: Hello matt. Thanks for reminding! I correct the ViewController_2.m file but the issue is still there...
Thank you, Darren. I will check the circular issue.

Comment: Try importing `AnimationObjectContainer.h` in the `ViewController_2.h` file.It solves the problem sometimes.

Comment: Thank you Andriko13. Seems like the issue is still there ... it really bothered me whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by my self.

I checked and modified these things then it works. But the warning message is still there. I'm not sure how to get rid of it ...

1. Check by breakpoint
   the parameter passed to method turned to weird value

self = (AnimationObjectContainer *)0x16657c30
seconds = (CGFloat)0.00000000000000000000000000000420389539

2. So I tried changing the argument type to int, and then it works.

self = (AnimationObjectContainer *)0x15e69940
seconds = (int)30

I am not sure what happened here but it did work.
Though, the warning message "instance method not found" is still there.

Comment: this is because the literal 30 is an int by default, you should use 30.0 in order to get a float literal